# SELECT INTO a variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have significant number of commands like:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email LIKE 'abc%');
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email LIKE 'abc%');
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email LIKE 'abc%');
```

How can I optimize it by extraction in a variable/list/array/set?

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email LIKE 'abc%'
```

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to only write the condition on which user to delete only once, you can use a data modifying CTE:

```
with user_list as (
   select id
   from users
   where email like 'abc%'
), delete_1 as (
   delete from table_1 where user_id in (select id from user_list)
), delete_1  as (
   delete from table_2 where user_id in (select id from user_list)
) 
delete from table_3 where user_id in (select id from user_list);
```

You still need to repeat the `select ...` for each delete but the *condition* on what needs to be deleted is only once in your statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can create temp table as

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE user_for_delete as
SELECT id 
FROM users 
WHERE email 
LIKE 'abc%';
```

and for any additional condition

```
INSERT INTO user_for_delete (id)
SELECT id 
FROM users 
WHERE email 
LIKE 'cdb%';
```

and finally delete from table1,2,3

```
DELETE FROM table1 t
USING user_for_delete u
WHERE u.id = t.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [data-modifying CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) like [@a_horse suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24700211/939860). But join in the derived table from first CTE in the [`DELETE` statements with the `USING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-delete.html). That's a bit shorter and faster:

```
WITH sel  AS (SELECT id FROM users WHERE email LIKE 'abc%')
,    del1 AS (DELETE FROM table_1 t USING sel WHERE t.user_id = sel.id)
,    del2 AS (DELETE FROM table_2 t USING sel WHERE t.user_id = sel.id) 
              DELETE FROM table_3 t USING sel WHERE t.user_id = sel.id;
```